# Can crooked surfaces alter speed messurement using a laser?

Tags: kinematics, reflection, laser, speed

this might be an unconventional question yet I think the physics community would be the one to help here.

Please hear me out.

So my problem/question:
I drove into a laser speed trap with my motorcycle going roughly 90 - 95 km/h (100% certain). I was allegedly measured with 141 km/h.

So since my bike has no license plate - which is used to measure the speed on a car - they chose to aim for my headlight which is super uneven and crooked.
Not being a flat reflective surface I was wondering if this could have altered the measurement of the laser making it think I was going faster than I did.

If a calculation is too hard I'd be thankful to be pointed in the right direction.

The laser used was a Riegl FG21-P (german police device). The distance I was measured from was 273 meters.

The headlight of my bike is the following:
https://autode-static.de/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/Fahrbericht-Yamaha-XJ6-Diversion-F-ABS-Kurvenspa-und-Alltagsroutine-4icg.jpg

I can provide the street section (on maps) if necessary. It was a slightly curved road (minimal).

Why I chose physics.stackexchange.com:
I'm a Software Dev and thought since Stackoverflow is our holy grail I might be able to find help here in the physics counterpart.

Comment: Laser Doppler doesn’t care about roughness of the reflecting surface.

Comment: What about crooked surfaces? That are at an angle to the laser and not like a flat 90 degree wall?

Comment: @JonCuster Laser speed traps usually don't use the Doppler effect, that's radar traps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, the roughness of the surface cannot alter the speed measured by a laser trap. We can see why if we look at how such a device measures your velocity.

First, it emits a light pulse which is reflected by whatever you are driving, and measures the time for that pulse to return to the device. Because the speed of light is much much faster than your typical road speed, your car/motorcycle can be viewed as stationary for this brief time period. By knowing how long it took the light to return, and knowing the speed of light, the device can calculate how far away the vehicle is.

Very shortly thereafter, it emits another pulse, and measures the distance in the same way. By knowing the two distances, it knows how far you travelled in that time. And dividing that distance by the time between the pulses, it deduces your velocity.

Now it could be that between these measurements the laser is now pointed at a different part of your vehicle, which would incorrectly alter the distance measured between two pulses. To counteract this, these devices usually take many measurements in a row, not just two, to avoid such errors. If the velocity fluctuates too much between successive pairs of pulses, the whole measurement is maked invalid. This rules out your *my headlight is uneven* defense.

Of course, there are countless other sources of error for wrong measurements with laser speed traps, but the surface being rough is not one of them.

Comment: Hey thanks for the thorough response! So I guess that the reflective parts inside the mirror that are crooked won't have an effect? I assumed that maybe it was because of weird reflections that the messurement was altered.
But like you have said maybe it was something with the device itself as I am 100% certain this messurement is not correct. Not sure how accurate it is to aim a laser at the headlights of a bike. I can't imagine that working when someone is going 141 km/h as it is quiet a small spot to hit and not at the usual height of license plates of cars.
Thanks again!

Comment: No matter how weird they are, if your vehicle doesn't show approximately the same speed in many consecutive measurements, the whole measurement will be invalid. So even if (extremely unlikely) the laser gets reflected around in your head light lots of times before coming back out, this will not give a valid reading on the laser gun.

Comment: Again, it doesn't matter what part of the vehicle gets hit by the laser. As long as some light makes it back to the gun, it will read your speed. If they aim for your headlight, but hit your shoulder, you will still reflect some of the laser light.

Comment: alright thanks a lot! guess it was a malfunction then. Probably hard to prove that. I just wish they would record a video while measuring... anyway thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I am in a similar situation as you. Was doing 125 kph on my motorcycle but got clocked by a cop with a laser gun for 170 kph today. I have a 2020 Yamaha R3 and I was also wondering how he was able to get that reading if I have a really small headlight. Did you end up having any luck with this? Thanks

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/393296)